# How does an EC2 instance access the Aws Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I have a .Net Core application that runs on an EC2 instance.
I am looking this application to get the secrets I have stored on the Secrets Manager.

I have created a IAM Role that allows the Ec2 instance to access the secrets manager.
However this is where I am stuck I don't know how to make use of that in my application nor can I find any tutorials online.
Could some one explain how my application should access this the instance profile so I can retrieve the from secrets manager through their API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to access the instance profile, the SDK does that for you. You just need to create a new instance of the client, and then use it.

```cs
var client = new Amazon.SecretsManager.AmazonSecretsManagerClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var response = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(new Amazon.SecretsManager.Model.GetSecretValueRequest
            {
                SecretId = "mySecretIdOrArn"
            });

var secretString = response.SecretString;
```

Comment: its saying no Region or Service URL provided

Comment: I edited it to include the region (assumed us-east-1, but you can set it to whatever).

Comment: Wdsworth - i got this changed however the error message is this now "Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service."

Comment: Sounds like the EC2 instance isn't configured correctly. I would look through [this trouble shooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_iam-ec2.html).

Comment: Really grateful for you help how do i run the following commands:$ GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname; echo

Comment: How do inject  in ec2 container via task like in ECS here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html